# What is the safest way to connect to database?

Tags: php, mysql

im wondering what is the best and safest way to make a connection to a database to include in all the php files where i have to get data from the database. right now i always make a connection every single time lets say i use a while to get some data from a certain table from database that looks like the code below. Can you guys tell me what is the best way to make a connection and use it for the while?

**How i make a connection for the while now every single time**

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    $select_data = mysql_select_db('databasename', $connect);
    $select_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE `id`='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_data)) {

        // Show profile pic.
        $oImgBox = $dom->getElementById('adminProfilePicture');
        $oImg = $dom->createElement('image');
        $oImg->setAttribute('src',$fetch["profilepic"]);
        $oImgBox->appendChild($oImg);
```

Comment: you concerned about safety yet you use mysql_*

Comment: Well, certainly not using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Well, @Dagon thats why i ask what is the safest and best way :(

Comment: @KingMike and searching around was never an option to you?

Comment: Consider using some database classes like PDO, and pass the PDO object to all your files

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated try using `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you obviously need to use either mysqli or prepared statements. But with that aside, if I am understanding correctly, I believe what you are looking for is the include() function.

With an include, you are able to put a particular script (such as db connection), on every page that requires it easily. See here http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

The first step is putting your PHP code into a standalone php file, such as db_connect.php or in your case user_profile.php. Then, for every page you need to make a connection to the database, you would add `include 'user_profile.php';` above your html.

**EDIT** - Adding sample DB connection script.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
  die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @EternalHour for the answer! So i looked at some pdo documentation but is it better to use prepared statements? if i get it right. u just make these prepared statements like a select and u can use it for every select you need to make then?

Comment: Here is the documentation on prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

I don't use PDO so I can't provide an expert opinion, but prepared statements would give you similar functionality and security of PDO. You will also notice that with mysqli, it supports object-oriented (prepared statements) and procedural (similar to mysql_* syntax but more secure).